# OnActionExecuted is not called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have a MVC application which has high traffic now. I am having issues with FilterAttribute. Sometimes `OnActionExecuted` is not called. Yes, I write and read database at filter but I have to. When I debug, I never encountered this problem, but there are a lot of users who have this issues, so I added log to write to file to track issue for some users who frequently face this issue. Now my filter roughly looks like following:

```
public class ManageReportLockAttribute
    : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    private ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public ManageReportLockAttribute()
    {       
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Logger.Log(controllerName, actionName, "Begin OnActionExecuting.");

        ............................

        Logger.Log(controllerName, actionName, "Complete OnActionExecuting.");
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {       
        Logger.Log(controllerName, actionName, "Begin OnActionExecuted.");

        .....................

        Logger.Log(controllerName, actionName, "Complete OnActionExecuted.");
    }
}
```

From the logs I see that *"Complete OnActionExecuting."* is logged for specific action, and *without* getting *"Begin OnActionExecuted."* for same action, I again get *"Begin OnActionExecuting."* for the **next action**. It is also clear from database that `OnActionExecuted` is not called according to values. It does not always occur, but sometimes. Also it is not *consistent* for one specific Action method. How is it possible? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try place this at controller level, it may be your action is being called from another action? Or an exception is causing this not to finish?

Comment: @Milney, I sometimes *Redirect* to another action methods, but even if I redirect, or there occurs *exception* should not `OnActionExecuted` run?

Comment: Which version of MVC are you running? I think 5 should certainly still run even with an exception but I am unsure of previous versions.. If you redirect properly it should still run it, but just to rule things out it might be worth a try adding it at controller level and seeing the difference?

Comment: @Milney, I am using MVC 5. If I can't find anything else, I will try your suggestion