# Locking entity in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

### **Short question**

How can I *lock* my entity so that **only one operation** by **only one user** can be performed on it at a time in MVC project?

### **Long question**

I have MVC project where I want my action methods to be `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]`. But when doing this users can execute another action methods even before one *long running* action method has not completed. As I have a lot calculations and action methods have to be executed in predefined order, executing another Action method before one ends creates lots of problems. To give example I have main entity called `Report`, I have to somehow ensure that one report undergoes **only one operation** by **only one user** at a time. So I have to *lock* my `Report`. Even if I do not use `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` I have to lock report so that multiple users do not edit same reports at a time and for other specific reasons. Currently I am writing this information to database roughly something like:

```
ReportId
LockedUserId
IsInPorcess
```

I have to set `IsInProcess` to `true` every time before operation *begins* and reset it to `false` after operation *completed*. As I have lots of action methods I created `ActionFilter` something like below:

```
public class ManageReportLockAttribute
    : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public ManageReportLockAttribute()
    {       
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ...
        ReportLockInfo lockInfo = GetFromDatabase(reportId);
        if(lockInfo.IsInProcess)
            RedirectToInformationView();

        lockInfo.IsInProcess = true;
        SaveToDatabase(lockInfo);
        ...
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {       
        ...
        ReportLockInfo lockInfo = GetFromDatabase(reportId);
        lockInfo.IsInProcess = false;
        SaveToDatabase(lockInfo);
        ...
    }
}
```

It works, for most part, but it has some strange problems (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44965464/1380428) for more info). 
My question is that "How can I achieve same functionality (locking report) by different *more acceptable* way?".
I feel like it is something similar to *locking* when using *multithreading*, but it is not  exactly same IMO.

Sorry for long, broad and awkward question, but I want a direction to follow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into atomic operations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx You would usually have some form of singleton which uses atomic operations and/or locks... Doing this in the database is probably not correct...

Comment: @Milney, thanks. Can you please help me to understand if I have multiple Reports whith differnt Ids, how I can lock them by `Interlocked` class?

Comment: IMO, marking the entity in the database as locked is exactly the right way. Think about having multiple webfrontend servers in a farm. Thread synchronization does not help in this case. To make sure that your application can scale well (even if you don't need it now), you need to lock at the database level. The database is shared among all webfrontend servers. However, you need to provide a mechanism to manually unlock the entity if anything goes wrong.

Comment: @Markus, thanks for information. But the applicaion is heavily used and this occurs frequently. Please see linked question for more inforamtion about problem. Now, I have only one applicaiton, so is there any better option for now at least?

Comment: @Markus - I'd say there is too much latency to use a database for this - if you need a distributed solution you will have to use a cache layer like Redis. Redis supports transactions: https://redis.io/topics/transactions

Comment: @Milney I agree that there are better options if you use other tools. Based on the current stack we know of, I wanted to point out that using thread synchronization has its weaknesses. I also agree that a performance hit is to be expected if you need to lock entities. It's always better to not have to lock them in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason why `OnActionExecuted` is not called though `OnActionExecuting` runs as expected is that there are unhandled exceptions that occur in `OnActionExecuting`. Especially when dealing with the database, there are various reasons that could lead to an exception, e.g.:

- User1 starts the process and locks the entity.
- User2 also wants to start the process before User1 has saved the change. So the check of `IsInProcess` does not lead to the redirection and User2 also wants to save the lock. In this case, a concurrency violation should occur because User1 has saved the entity in the meantime.

To illustrate the process over time (C is the check whether `IsInProcess` is set, S is `SaveChanges`): first a good case:

```
User1     CS  
User2       CS (check is done after save, no problem)
```

Now a bad case:

```
User1     CS  
User2      CS (check takes place after check for User1, but before SaveChanges becomes effective ==> concurrency violation)
```

As the example shows, it is critical to make sure that only one user can place the lock. There are several ways to handle this. In all cases make sure that there are as few reasons for exceptions in `OnActionExecuting` as possible. Handle and log the exceptions.

Please note that all synchronisation methods will have a negative impact on the performance of your application. **So if you haven't already thought about whether you could avoid having to lock the report by restructuring your actions or the data model, this would be the first thing to do.**

## Easy approach: thread synchronisation

An easy approach is to use thread synchronisation. This approach will only work if the application runs in a single process and not in a web farm/the cloud. You need to decide whether you will be able to change the application if it will be installed in a farm at a later point in time. This sample shows an easy approach (that uses a static object for locking):

```
public class ManageReportLockAttribute
    : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    private static readonly object lockObj = new object();
    // ...    
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ...
        ReportLockInfo lockInfo = GetFromDatabase(reportId);
        if(lockInfo.IsInProcess)
          RedirectToInformationView();
        lock(lockObj)
        {
          // read anew just in case the lock was set in the meantime
          // A new context should be used.
          lockInfo = GetFromDatabase(reportId); 
          if(lockInfo.IsInProcess)
            RedirectToInformationView();
          lockInfo.IsInProcess = true;
          SaveToDatabase(lockInfo);
          ...
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
      ...
      lock(lockObj)
      {
        lockInfo = GetFromDatabase(reportId);
        if (lockInfo.IsInProcess) // check whether lock was released in the meantime
        {
          lockInfo.IsInProcess = false;
          SaveToDatabase(lockInfo);
        }
        ...
      }
    }
}
```

For details on using `lock` see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement). If you need more control, have a look at the [overview of thread synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/thread-synchronization) with C#. A named mutex is an alternative that provides locking in a more fine coarsed manner.

If you want to lock on `reportId` instead of a static object, you need to use a lock object that is the same for the same `reportId`. A dictionary can store the lock objects:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<int, object> lockObjectsByReportId = new Dictionary<int, object>();

private static object GetLockObjectByReportId(int reportId)
{
  int lockObjByReportId;
  if (lockObjectsByReportId.TryGetValue(reportId, out lockObjByReportId))
    return lockObjByReportId;
  lock(lockObj)  // use global lock for a short operation
  {
    if (lockObjectsByReportId.TryGetValue(reportId, out lockObjByReportId))
      return lockObjByReportId;
    lockObjByReportId = new object();
    lockObjectsByReportId.Add(reportId, lockObjByReportId);
    return lockObjByReportId;
  }
}
```

Instead of using `lockObj` in `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted`, you'd use the function:

```
// ...
lock(GetLockObjectByReportId(reportId))
{
  // ...
}
```

## Database approach: Transactions and isolation levels

Another way to handle this is to use database transactions and isolation levels. This approach will also work in a multi-server environment. In this case, you'd not use the entity framework for database access but move the code to a stored procedure that is run on the database server. By running the stored procedure in a transaction and picking the right isolation level, you can avoid that a user can read the data while another one is changing them.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels) shows an overview of isolation levels for SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I think no exception occurs during `OnActionExecuting`. Because, there is no sign of logged error (I use Elmah for this purpose), and I logged *Complete OnActionExecuting* in the last line of `OnActionExecuting` method, and it is logged. I have question about `lock`. I think it will lock my attribute accorss the system? Am I right? Will not it slow down process a lot?

Comment: The sample implementation uses a static object for locking. You are right that this lock affects all users that access any of the methods at the same time. Of course you can implement a more fine coarsed solution that takes the reportId or some other value for locking and thus is not that broad.

Comment: I almost have never used lock keyword, can you please show how can I consider reportId while locking?

Comment: I've extended the sample. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it and let you know if I was successful

Comment: Hi. I am still having some issues according to this problem. Can we chat or connect somehow?

Comment: @AdilMammadov Sorry, I don't have too much time these days. I'm pretty sure that implementing this in a stable way requires a lot of effort. Maybe you can rethink the requirement and change to an optimistic locking approach. That means that users can edit the data simultaneously, but will receive an error when they save. Also you could think about why users need to edit the same entity so often. There might be a way that you change the model and have the users edit different entities. Might be better than trying to fix the locking mechanism over and over.

Comment: No problem. I have divided entities into smaller parts already as much as possible. This problem is rare, but occurs and I don't want it to happen. I think I will try to lock using `SemaphoreSlim` as I use `async/await`. Thanks again.